Is the union of discrete subsets discrete if they are linearly ordered by the subset relation?
Let $(X, \mathcal{T})$ be a topological space, $\mathcal{U} \subset \mathcal{P}(X)$ be discrete subsets, $\mathcal{U}$ be linearly $\subset$-ordered, and $\bigcup \mathcal{U} = X$. Is $\mathcal{T}$ discrete?
A subset $X' \subset X$ is discrete if $\mathcal{T}|X' = \mathcal{P}(X')$, i.e. all sets are open in the subspace topology.
Some easy cases are:

The claim holds if $X \in \mathcal{U}$.
The claim holds if $\mathcal{U} \subset \mathcal{T}$.


What is a "discrete subset"?

@Randall All sets are open in the subspace topology. Added a note.

No, $X = \mathbb{Q}$ and $U_k = \frac{1}{k!} \mathbb{Z}$. Then $U_k$ is an increasing sequence of discrete subsets whose union is $X$, but $X$ is not discrete.

It's simple, but still awesome :D I thought about how dyadic rationals won't do the job.

@kaba Any countable space is the union of a chain of finite subsets, which will be discrete if the space is $T_1$.

@user14111 You're right. That's even simpler.
